# Generating 2 documents with one Jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a database with questions and answers that I use to create tests.

I don't have any problems to generate an unanswered test but I would like to generate the unanswered test (for students) and the answered test (for the teacher)

I mean, in the same pdf I want to create the 2 versions of the same test. At the beginning of the document one version and when it version is finished then generating the other version but all in the same pdf document.

I can not do two different buttons, one for each version, because the order of the answers is random.

Do you have any idea about how to do it? is it possible to add additional bands of title, detail,... at the end of the documento?

Thanks

Comment: `Do you have any idea about how to do it? With subreports? With additional bands?` - You can use subreport or list component. Maybe the table element will be the good choice. It depends on. Your question is too broad

Comment: I am sorry, maybe my English is not good enough. I have edited the information in order to explain better

Answer (score 0):

You can use two tables in the single detail band of the report and different parameters for the two tables as below:

`JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource1 = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(unanswered);
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource2=new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(answered);
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("Unnswered", beanColDataSource1);
parameters.put("Answered",beanColDataSource2);`

Now create two parameters in your jasper main report and use these parameters as datasource in both of your tables.
Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem would be that in the same document I would have both documents and when it is printed students would see both